# Python set xticks (want it to be 0:00-1:00, 1:00-2:00, ...)

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib

I want to set the x-tick of my plot to be `0:00-1:00`, `1:00-2:00`, ...`23:00-0:00`, instead of the original `0, 1, 2, ..., 23`

So I used:

```
plt.xticks(['0:00-1:00', '1:00-2:00', '2:00-3:00', '3:00-4:00', '4:00-5:00', '5:00-6:00', '6:00-7:00', '7:00-8:00',
            '8:00-9:00', '9:00-10:00', '10:00-11:00', '11:00-12:00', '12:00-13:00', '13:00-14:00', '14:00-15:00',
            '15:00-16:00', '16:00-17:00', '17:00-18:00', '18:00-19:00', '19:00-20:00', '20:00-21:00', '21:00-22:00',
            '22:00-23:00', '23:00-24:00'])
```

But I got this error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 9:00-10:00
```

So how can I achieve my goal? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your code does not work is because you are using strings directly in `xticks`. you should create a list (in my example `labels`) and then assign it to your `xticks` as a parameter.

An example code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0,10,5)
y = np.sin(x)

labels = ['0:00-1:00', '1:00-2:00', '2:00-3:00', '3:00-4:00', '4:00-5:00'] # My manual xticks

plt.scatter(x,y)
plt.xticks(x,labels') # Here we assign it to xticks 
                      # Rotate them using "rotation='vertical'"
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't have enough reputation to do so, though I would love to. I've just started to use stack over flow :p